# How can I get Apple Maps and Google Maps to *always* show speed limits?

Tags: ios, maps, google-maps

I'm on iOS 15.2.1, and I've enabled the display of speed limits in both Apple Maps and Google Maps. Both apps show the speed limit if I'm using them to navigate somewhere, but if I'm just using them to show me where I am while I'm driving around, neither shows me the speed limit.  How can I get them to show me the current speed limit, regardless of whether I'm using them to navigate to a destination?

Answer (score 1):

For both apps, speed limits are only displayed when actually navigating to a destination.  If you're not in a navigation session, the speed limits will not be displayed.

I have not read of any upcoming features that would change how this functions to get what you want.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the apps have this behavior? If I'm not navigating, both track my route, updating the map constantly. What's the rationale for hiding relevant information like the current speed limit?

Comment: No idea, it's just how both company's designed their apps to work.

Answer (score 0):

When I texted Apple support they said:

> Apple Maps does not have a specific speedometer, but you can activate Speed Limit so that you can see what speed you are allowed to drive in the places where it is available. However, you must be aware that you only see Speed Limit when you are navigating.
>
> Go to:
> Settings -> Maps, then tap Driving. From there you can toggle Speed Limit on.